# How do I use auto layout to align images horizontal to each other

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, autolayout, uistoryboard

[image: Screenshot]

So here's my problem, I'm attempting to align the two green images relative to the superview, so that they retain the same position on all the possible iPhone screen sizes, but I noticed that when i pin trailing, leading, bottom and top edges of both to the superview, the left image appears correctly but the right image appears squashed on iPhones with smaller widths (e.g 5, 4S, 5S).

I can only assume that the constraints of the left image are inevitably affecting the constraints of the one on the right. Although I'm not too new to auto layouts, I've never had to deal with a situation of this nature before, What changes do I need to make to ensure that the images appear like this on all screens, especially ones with smaller widths.

PS: Reducing the actual sizes of both images didn't solve the issue either.

Thanks.

UPDATE: I would like the space between the images to shrink/grow according to the screen size. The space between them isn't my goal, my goal is getting the images to appear trailing and leading the superview as shown in the screenshot, not necessarily relative to each other.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Are you trying to keep the distance between those two images equal across devices and then keep both of them relatively centered horizontally?

Comment: Hi @Nebs just updated the question to reflect your comment, The images don't have to maintain that distance, in fact, I want the distance between them to grow (on larger screens) and shrink (on smaller screens) so that each image always has the same distance from the edge of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but what I would do is:

Left image:

1. Pin the "left" and "top" edges to the superview.
2. Pin the width
   and height

Right image:

1. Pin the "right" and "top" edges to the superview
2. Pin the width and height

Don't pin the two images to each other. Also, don't pin the right image's left edge or the left image's right edge.  There's no reason to pin the bottom edge either because you can fix the height (assuming you want the size of the images to remain fixed).

Comment: You sir, are a brilliant man! This works perfectly! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another way you can do it like this Ctrl+Drag from One view to the Other and chose either Top, Bottom, or Centre according to your requirement [image]